# Dante Labs VCF: UPDATE: SOLVED

Tags: assembly, chromosomes

Has anyone tried to analyse the VCF files provided by Dante Labs? (Human WGS, Illumina)

I'm looking into .raw.vcf and .filtered.vcf.

For reference sequence, all I can see is 2 contigs:
GL000225.1 and GL000192.1.
All variants belong to one of these.
There's no conventional CHROM column.

I don't know how those coordinates map to chromosomes in GRCh37 or GRCh38 assemblies.

- GL000192 [corresponds](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?db=hg19&chromInfoPage=) to chr1_gl000192_random
- GL000225 [corresponds](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTracks?db=hg19&chromInfoPage=) to chrUn_gl000225

Moreover, there's no VCF header with metainfo, all I can see is 1 top row

```
:11,27:0.711:38:4,11:7,16:25:64,0,24:2.8811e+01,1.4126e-02,2.7139e+01:0.00,34.77,37.77:6,5,12,15:7,4,18,9.
```

1. What's the use of those VCFs?
2. What variants do they contain?
3. What version of VCF it is and where can I get the standard metainfo?
4. Is there a map of those coordinates to any core assembly
   chromosomes?
5. Am I right they contain not all genomic VCFs but only a small part
   of the genome? (Size of GL000225.1 contig is 211,173 bp and size of
   GL000192.1 is 547,496 bp, that obviously doesn't sum up to the whole
   genome).

Many thanks for your replies!

UPD: I found a mistake, sorry. The file was incomplete, only tail was uploaded to Jupyterhub.
In local Jupyter, the file loaded completely, it actually has the  header and CHROM column.